# Css link button with padding not respecting top and bottom margins

Tags: html, css, button, web, undefined-behavior

This button is not respecting margin-top and margin-bottom, and i have no idea why...

```
.button {
    background: #E48F8F;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;
    background-color:DeepSkyBlue;
    color:white;
    font-family:'Gotham Book';
    font-size:15px; 
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="side_bar">
     <h3>Veja Também</h3>
     <div class="separator"></div>
     <div class="side_bar_item">
         <img src="img/psicoterpia.jpg" />
         <h3>Psicoterapia</h3>
         <p>A Psicoterapia é uma prática clínica desenvolvida e aplicada por psicólogos, com o intuito de oferecer, tanto para os que têm uma queixa definida ou não, condições que proporcionem mais auto-conhecimento e, consequentemente, um melhor estilo de vida. Existem diversas abordagens e cada uma delas atende melhor a um determinado tipo de indivíduo.</p>
         <a href="#" class="button">Saiba Mais</a>
     </div>   
</div>
```

here's a picture of what's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `.button` display property to `block` or `inline-block`

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

By default an `a` tag will be set to `display: inline` and will not respect `margin` properties.

See this [JSFIddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleyflood/HCUgP/) and take a look at [CSS display Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) on W3Schools

Answer (score 1):

You can put certain parts in a `div` which has a `class` for its features.  [See example you can play with](http://jsfiddle.net/v7qKe/).

```
<div class="side_bar">
     <h3>Veja Também</h3>

    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="side_bar_item">
        <img src="img/psicoterpia.jpg" />
         <h3>Psicoterapia</h3>

        <p>A Psicoterapia é uma prática clínica desenvolvida e aplicada por psicólogos, com o intuito de oferecer, tanto para os que têm uma queixa definida ou não, condições que proporcionem mais auto-conhecimento e, consequentemente, um melhor estilo de vida. Existem diversas abordagens e cada uma delas atende melhor a um determinado tipo de indivíduo.</p>
        <div class="Button-look"> <a href="#" class="button">Saiba Mais</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS would look like this

```
.button {
    background: #E48F8F;
    border: 0;
    padding: 15px 45px 15px 45px;
    background-color:DeepSkyBlue;
    color:black;
    font-family:'Gotham Book';
    font-size:20px;
}
.Button-look {
    margin-top:20px;
}
}
```

Comment: This is an alternative solution, but it's not 100% effective. I would have to put extra margin on the bottom... But if i don't find a real solution, i'll stick with this. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="side_bar">

        <h3>Veja Também</h3>

        <div class="separator"></div>


        <div class="side_bar_item">

            <img src="img/psicoterpia.jpg" />

            <h3>Psicoterapia</h3>

                <p>A Psicoterapia é uma prática clínica desenvolvida e aplicada por 
psicólogos, com o intuito de oferecer, tanto para os que têm uma queixa definida ou
não, condições que proporcionem mais auto-conhecimento e, consequentemente, um melhor 
estilo de vida. Existem diversas abordagens e cada uma delas atende melhor a um 
determinado tipo de indivíduo.</p>
            <br>
             <a href="#" class="button" style="color: white" width="100%">Saiba
             Mais</a>
            </br>
        </div>
```

Try adding the line brakes and style="color: white" width="100%"

Comment: This works visually, but still not getting the margin property from the css. I would have to simulate the margin with line break,s that's not cool.